# Remote images in Pdf apache fop

Tags: apache, pdf-generation, apache-fop

We are generating pdf from XML using apache fop version 1.0. In this we are trying to load image which is remotely located. I am seeing plenty of example how to give relative URL. Can anyone tell me how to give absolute URL which is remotely located?

Comment: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for http://example.com/wcsstore/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/attachments/images/fridge/thumbnail/SR-IT-SCREWS-200-1A.jpg (No context info available)
I am getting above exception.

Comment: What have you tried? share your code

Comment: There could be a problem in the image URL (missing protocol, wrong kind of slash, ...), so I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45072747/edit) your question to include an actual FO fragment producing the error (just the `fo:external-graphic` element). Moreover, is there a specific reason for using version 1.0 which is several years old?